# Image not closing because function is still using it

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a save method that looks like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.avatar:
        image = Image.open(self.avatar)
        image_path = self.avatar.path
        image_name = self.avatar.path[:-4]
        image_ext = self.avatar.path[-4:]
        resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext)
        image.close()
```

When I trigger the save method once, it works. However, when I trigger it again I get an error: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: xxxx`

I have an overwrite method that will go in and clean the directory and then save the new image. However, since the previous image did not close yet and it's still in "use" it's giving this error. When I remove the `resize_images` method, everything works and I don't get the error. This is how `resize_images` looks like:

```
def resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext):
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(image_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    medium_image = image.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.close()
    medium_path = image_name + "_medium" + image_ext
    medium_image.save(medium_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    small_image = medium_image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    small_path = image_name + "_small" + image_ext
    small_image.save(small_path, optimize=True, quality=95)
    medium_image.close()

    mini_image = small_image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    mini_path = image_name + "_mini" + image_ext
    mini_image.save(mini_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    small_image.close()
    mini_image.close()
```

So basically what happens is user uploads profile picture, the overwrite function checks if images exist in the directory, if they do it removes them, the save method will then take the new image, resize it into multiple thumbnails and then save. How can I fix the permission error? I'm closing the images, yet I still get the error...

Comment: I have faced similar problem before when I was making the interface for profile picture as well.
I used `os.remove(image/path)` and then added the new image on the same path.

Comment: Where is the remove function? Is it being called parallel to the `resize_images`?